# "Nobody had a clear idea for what or where they supposed to search."

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

> "Nobody had a clear idea ***for what*** or where they supposed to search."

Does this construction look natural for natives?

I am trying to avoid ending the sentence with a preposition that would incorrectly modify also the adverb ***where***.

Thanks.

Comment: "Nobody had a clear idea for what or where they **were** supposed to search."

Comment: A very minor point: I'd make it *where or for what*, to avoid even a momentary implication that *where* is an object of *for*.

Comment: You could also append **for what**. *Nobody had a clear idea where they were supposed to search—or for what.*   Quite a ragged crew, those searchers.

Comment: Somebody should ask: Why do you want to avoid ending with a preposition? _Nobody had any clue where to search, or what they were looking for_. There's [nothing wrong with that version](https://www.google.com/search?q=ending+a+sentence+with+a+preposition).

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for your suggestion. I avoided ending with the aforementioned preposition because the next sentence also included it. I put a little bit of space between the two **for**.

Comment: That’s an important detail you should have not omitted.

Answer (score 1):

> Nobody had a clear idea for what or where they supposed to search.

This is fine, except that there is a small chance it could be interpreted as:

> Nobody had a clear idea for what or for where they supposed to search

So this:

> Nobody had a clear idea where or for what they supposed to search

is a bit clearer.

In this:

> Nobody had a clear idea where or what they supposed to search for.

there's little to no chance that anyone would attach the *for* to *where*.  But it still sounds a bit awkward because it sounds like you tacked on the words "or what they were supposed to search for" without much forethought - which is fine in speech, but in writing, you have the time to think about it.

Comment: I chose the last but one, indeed, also specifying the perfect tense of the verb, **were supposed**. Thank you for your elaborate explanation!